# Error Descarga con file InputStream/OutputStream y FacesContext/ExternalContext

Tags: java, mvc, jsf, xhtml

He Creado un metodo que realiza la descarga de un archivo , desde una base de datos postgre, el archivo esta en byte, lo convierto y procedo a realizar la descarga, cuando realice la prueba con un archivo jpg, estatico me descargaba sin problemas, pero al colocar, dinamica la cabecera del archivo no realiza la descarga. me muestra la imagen en el navegador y si es un .zip me da la opcion de descargar el .html

```
    public void download(Long idHistorid) throws Exception{
    ListAllIsueDetailDTO downAttachament = new ListAllIsueDetailDTO();
    downAttachament = IssueDelegate.getInstance().readAllHistorid(idHistorid);
    atacheByte = downAttachament.getListAllIsueDetailDTO().get(0).getIssueDetailAttachmentDTO().getIssueDeatailattachemedBinary();
    atachemeType = downAttachament.getListAllIsueDetailDTO().get(0).getIssueDetailAttachmentDTO().getIssueDetailAttachameType();
    nameAttachmanet = downAttachament.getListAllIsueDetailDTO().get(0).getIssueDetailAttachmentDTO().getNameAttachment();
    String[] atachmentExt = atachemeType.split("/");
    String atachmentFinalExt = atachmentExt[1];
    try {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext(); 


        externalContext.responseReset();
        externalContext.setResponseContentType(atachemeType);
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition","\"attachament;filename=\\"+atachemeType+"."+atachmentFinalExt+"\\\"" );

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(atacheByte);
        OutputStream outputStream = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();

        int length;
        byte[] buffer  = new byte[1024];
        while((length =inputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        context.responseComplete();



    }catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("error" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías compartir tu código y especificar en que partes te ocasiona problemas?

Comment: creo que el pricipal error esta aquí.   externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition","\"attachament;filename=\\"+atachemeType+"."+atachmentFinalExt+"\\\"" );

Comment: Veo que dice "attachament" en vez de "attachment" remueve una "a"

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente ese era uno de los errores y le faltaba un espacio, quedaría así para que la cabecera funcione perfecto. "\"attachment; filename=\\"